# How Group Key Json, Sum, and dynamically?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

I have a json column in my mariadb server. I get a problem : I can't group json.

I have tried using procedures and functions but failed continuously
I hope to include ways to get this solution to friends who are better at this than I am a beginner

Sample data :

```
id   name           json
------------------------------------------------------
1    lorem ipsum    {"a":2,"b": 10, "c": 20}
2    lorem ipsum2   {"a":1, "b":8, "c": 21, "d":7}
2    lorem ipsum2   {"b":1, "e":8, "h": 21, "j":7}
```

Now i want the output data like this, calculate the value and dinamically if data increase A to Z of the json object :

```
key  average  max_value  min_value  sum_value  count_data
---------------------------------------------------------
a    1.5      2          1          3          2
b    8.2      10         1          19         3
c    20.5     21         20         41         2
d    7        7          7          7          1
```

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` fixed values, or we need to dynamically build the list of keys from the content of the data ?

Comment: @GMB I want to be dynamic. my friend. Thank you in advance

Comment: . do you have a solution? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample data shows results for only 4 keys, while there are more than that in your data. Here is a solution if you want the results for a fixed set of keys ; it uses a subquery to list the keys that should be taken into account, and *conditional aggregation* in the outer query ; `JSON_EXTRACT` lets you access the content of the objects :

```
SELECT
    v.val,
    AVG(JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$.', v.val))) AS average,
    MAX(JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$.', v.val))) AS max_value,
    MIN(JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$.', v.val))) AS min_value,
    SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$.', v.val))) AS sum_value,
    COUNT(JSON_EXTRACT(js, CONCAT('$.', v.val))) AS count_data
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'a' val UNION ALL SELECT'b' UNION ALL SELECT'c' UNION ALL SELECT'd'
) v
GROUP BY v.val
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/MxyUJiPTBDf2cNM4S8B3P/0)** :

```
| val | average | max_value | min_value | sum_value | count_data |
| --- | ------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ---------- |
| a   | 1.5     | 2         | 1         | 3         | 2          |
| b   | 6.3333  | 8         | 1         | 19        | 3          |
| c   | 20.5    | 21        | 20        | 41        | 2          |
| d   | 7       | 7         | 7         | 7         | 1          |
```

---

If your tag values range fro `a` to `z`, one (ugly but working) solution is to expand the subquery with more `UNION ALL SELECT`s.

Comment: thanks my friend. now i want to add dynamic data if the data increases from A to Z. do you have a solution? I appreciate your help

Comment: @YovanggaAnandhika : you can expand the subquery until `... UNION ALL SELECT'z'`